# Centos 9 stream and PHP 7.4 problem SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, centos

I am using PHP 7.4 on centos 9 stream version.
and running a web service by connecting to MySQL and SQL Server database servers.

There is no problem with MySQL, but there is intermittent connection delay when connecting to SQL Server.

It's fine right after the server starts up, but after a while, when users start to attach little by little, it stops.

There weren't many users, and I thought it was a firewall problem, so I turned it off, but it's still there.

This is a situation where you are repeating apply and rollback.
Please help.

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x102
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Is the SQL Server also on the same machine? SQL Server isn't supported on CentOS. ref: [SQL Server on Linux Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-faq)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
The DB server is on a separate server.

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't closing connections properly, so the IOCP listener is overloaded. You need to close all connections in a `finally` block

Comment: @Charlieface After connecting to the DB, the connection is automatically closed after the query is executed. It doesn't seem like an overload. I'll check it out.

Comment: How about you show some code.